# Downloadable/Printable 3D Model of Cylinder Seal

Tags: mesopotamia

My son's high school has some 3D printers and I thought it might be interesting to see if they could print out a cylinder seal. Does anyone know of any 3D models online of real historical cylinder seals? My searching hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: Have you looked at the collection of [3D printer models](https://sketchfab.com/britishmuseum) that the British Museum has uploaded to SketchFab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 3d Model of a Sumerian Seal [(Cylinder Seal VA-243)](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1597817)
Here is the resulting print

[image]